# Removing empty list elements from a sql coalesce string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query that has this syntax

```
coalesce(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_creator] as varchar) + ',', '') + coalesce(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer1] as varchar) + ',','') + coalesce(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer2] as varchar) + ',', '') + coalesce(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer3] as varchar) + ',','') + coalesce(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer4] as varchar) + ',', '') + coalesce(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer5] as varchar),'') as admin_list
```

F_member_id_creator is always present in the db, however f_member_id_officer1 through 5 may be available in any combination.

For example, a returned value from the above statement might be

"25431,32663,,,,"
or "25431,,32663,,,"
or "25431,,,32663,,"
or "25431,,,,32663,"

etc.

What I need to do is tell SQL to remove the empty list elements and just return "25431,32663"

Any way to do this in SQL Server 2005?

Or better yet, have it not select the empty ordinal at all if its null or blank?

Comment: this table's structure looks definitely like ... a schema smell !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU got the result because `[tb_groups].[f_member_id_creator]`, maybe, the empty instead of `null`. Try this:

```
coalesce(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_creator] as varchar))), '') + ',', '') + ...
```

If you agree that you haven't trailing and/or leading spaces you can omit LTRIM/RTRIM.

Comment: This wasn't it but it did send me down the right path. Seems I just needed to rearrange my commas.

,coalesce
    (
     cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_creator] as varchar), '') 
     + coalesce(',' + cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer1] as varchar),'') 
     + coalesce(',' + cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer2] as varchar),'') 
     + coalesce(',' + cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer3] as varchar),'') 
     + coalesce(',' + cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer4] as varchar),'') 
     + coalesce(',' + cast([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer5] as varchar),''
    ) as admin_list

Comment: Be attentive, that can't be the trick. The both versions are practically similar.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified above code... I think it works... because it worked for me

```
COALESCE(CAST([tb_groups].[f_member_id_creator] as varchar), '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(',' + CAST([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer1] as varchar),','), '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(',' + CAST([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer2] as varchar),','), '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(',' + CAST([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer3] as varchar),','), '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(',' + CAST([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer4] as varchar),','), '') + 
COALESCE(NULLIF(',' + CAST([tb_groups].[f_member_id_officer5] as varchar),','), '') as admin_list
```